# Change color of text letter by letter on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to recreate this style from a website: https://www.polestar.com/us/polestar-1/
On the third section which is titled as "Precision", thats kind of style I want to recreate.. Like how it changed paragraph text color from white to rgb(211, 188, 141).. and removes the sticky position when it finish changing the text color..

How this works?

I tried to use the same method as they did, using different elements as  for each letter and hide the letter white letter as we scroll but I am not sure with the js

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example We are very happy to help debug your code but we aren’t here to write it ab initio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example. I have tried to comment everything that happens carefully in the JS.

```js
// at what yPosition should we stick?
const stickyAtYPos = 100;
// minumum time between coloring a character
const minTimeColorCharMs = 50;

// browser, do not remember scroll positions for me
history.scrollRestoration = "manual";

// a flag that is set later (yPos to lock the scroll at)
// + which sticky that is currently locked
// + lastTime we colored a span
let lockedAt, lockedSticky, lastColorTime = 0;


// divide text inside .stickyColor elements
// into one span per character
[...document.querySelectorAll('.stickyColor')]
  .forEach(x => x.innerHTML = '<span>'
    + x.innerText.trim().split('')
      .join('</span><span>') + '</span>');

// listen to the scroll event of the window
window.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  // if scroll is locked and the user scrolls down 
  // and time enough between coloring characters
  if (lockedAt && window.scrollY > lockedAt &&
    (!lastColorTime || Date.now() - lastColorTime > minTimeColorCharMs)) {
    // find the first uncolored span
    let span = [...lockedSticky.querySelectorAll('span')]
      .find(x => !x.classList.contains('newColor'));
    // color it and remember when we did that
    span && span.classList.add('newColor') || (lastColorTime = Date.now());
    // if no more spans to color, release the scroll lock
    !span && (lockedAt = false);
  }
  // if locked, then don't allow scroll down
  lockedAt && window.scrollY > lockedAt && window.scrollTo(0, lockedAt);
  // get the stickycolor elements
  let stickies = [...document.querySelectorAll('.stickyColor')];
  // loop through them
  stickies.forEach((sticky, i) => {
    // if we have a lock already do nothing
    if (lockedAt) { return; }
    // check if the sticky should stick :)
    if (sticky.getBoundingClientRect().top < stickyAtYPos
      && !sticky.classList.contains('locked')) {
      // remember y pos to lock scroll at + locked sticky
      lockedAt = window.scrollY;
      lockedSticky = sticky;
      // add class signaling that we are locked
      sticky.classList.add('locked');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  margin: 20px 30px;
  color: white;
}

p.stickyColor {
  font-family: 'Verdana';
  margin-top: 200px;
  top: 100px;
  transition: color 1s;
}

p.stickyColor span {
  color: white;
  transition: color 0.1s;
}

p.stickyColor span.newColor {
  color: rgb(192, 143, 35);
}

.big {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Sticky Color</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Please scroll down...</p>
  <p class="stickyColor">Hello there! Nice to see you!</p>
  <p class="stickyColor">Let's play a game of colors...</p>
  <p class="stickyColor">Goodbye everyone! That's all.</p>
  <div class="big"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

*Note*: Although you can't see it here, the script needs to be included as the last element in the body, since all elements need to be in the DOM before it runs and I'm not waiting for document ready...

Comment: Nice. Can you reset it when scrolling back up?

Comment: Wouldn't resetting it when scrolling back be very irritating from the users perspective? (I would think so...) Constant locking of the scroll when you want to go move up and down in the content...

Comment: That might be true

Comment: @mplungjan: It is doable though, but I already spent too much time on this one... so not by me. (Too much screen-time warning... ;) )

Comment: Yeah, I answered too and was not completely happy so I deleted my answer since yours was better. I had two sets of spans and did `const index = Math.floor(scrollTop / elementHeight); if (normalSpan) normalSpan.style.opacity = (i < index ? 1 : 0);
    if (colorSpan) colorSpan.style.opacity = (i >= index ? 1 : 0);`

Comment: @mplungjan: Your answer was a good starting point, though (I upvoted it)

Comment: What I'm not completely happy about in mine is that it's 'shakes' if you scroll fast (worse in this small 'test window' than on a bigger viewport, but: To fix that you would have to add event listeners to wheel, touchstart and touchmove, set them to {passive: false} and call event.preventDefault, but at the same time read which direction the user wanted to scroll (from wheel e.yDelta, on touchmove by looking a changed pointer...) Too much work right now. But that would fix the shakiness, I would do it if going live with a pro version.